# icmp smurf attack

Tags: network, attacks, router, ddos, icmp

I am learning about ICMP smurf attack and for this, I have forged a packet with the following details:

```
  source_mac_address = **??**
  destination_mac_address = router mac address
  char source_ip_address = victim ip address (within subnet)
  char destination_ip_address = "142.250.193.78"; // google.com
```

Now, if I am putting my own (attacker) host mac address in source_mac_address, it is working fine.
But if I put the address of the victim in source_mac_address I don't see an echo reply on the victim.

I want to understand why this is not working, as the router would not know whether the packet was received from host A or host B.

Comment: what is your network topology?

Comment: a simple router with 2 connected nodes in same subnet.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the following is your network topology (as you mention in your [comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/269064/icmp-smurf-attack?noredirect=1#comment559486_269064)):

```
victim (mac A) -----
                    |
                 (port A) 
               switch+router ---- (internet) --- (google)
                 (port B)
                    |
attacker (mac B) ---
```

One key point to note here is that a home router is *usually* a combination of a router and a switch, which schematically can be understood by the following functional diagram:

```
   port A
     |
   switch --- router --- internet
     |
   port B
```

This is important, because a switch works as follows (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71840907) and [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/34759)):

- it receives a frame from a port (that's what you plug your cables into)
- it associates this port with the mac address of the received frame
- if it receives a frame with the mac address of the frame in the previous point from a different port, it *replaces* the previous entry (port/mac association) with a new one (new port/mac association)

So, a **simplified**<sup>[a]</sup> answer to your question is that since you sent a packet from port B (see the network topology) with the victim's mac, that means that the switch associates *port B* with the *victim's mac* (replacing the previous association of port A/victim's mac). At this point, when the reply from google comes, the switch forwards it to port B, but the address on the reply is the *victim's* (both mac and IP), not the attacker's. Because of this, the reply does not reach any box because at port B there's no box with the victim's mac and IP address.

As a natural consequence, you won't see the reply from the victim either, because the reply is forwarded to port B, not to port A (where the victim is listening on).

---

<sup>[a]</sup> Simplified, because in reality you will have more complicated traffic patterns and, as such, you will encounter issues like [mac flapping](https://www.kareemccie.com/2017/08/what-is-mac-flapping.html) and/or erratic traffic behaviour. For further details you can read the linked answers above

Comment: @Spyors i am using a wireless router, and both are connected to same SSID.